# Adding SWIPE functionality to a Nivo Lightbox?

Tags: jquery, iframe, lightbox, swipe, nivo-slider

I have used the Nivo Lightbox provided by http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-lightbox/ on a website I am working on and I cannot seem to get it to touch slide/swipe while in the gallery mode.

I have had a look around and cannot find a workable answer online. The two that I did find, didn't work, or shall I say I couldn't get them to work. I know this feature can work as it up and running on this site: www.imageworkshop.com/2013/06/19/dance-performer-promo-photography/

Thanks in advance to anyone that does respond to this.

http://crazyway.tv/test1/videos.php

Update!

I have managed to get the swipe working partially, only above and below the lightbox content

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('body').touchwipe({
            wipeLeft: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-next").click(); },
            wipeRight: function(){ jQuery(".nivo-lightbox-prev").click(); },
             min_move_x: 70,
             min_move_y: 70,                 
             preventDefaultEvents: false                 
        });
    });     
    </script>
```

I believe the issues is get it to work over an iframe...

Comment: `The two that i did find, didn't work` - can you post what have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209119/nivo-lightbox-notopening-on-an-iphone-but-does-work-on-ipad and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989000/adding-swipe-functionality-to-a-lightbox/20172628#20172628

They are very similar...

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin: https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin

code to use:

```
$(function(){
    var addSwipeTo = function(selector) {  
        $(selector).swipe("destroy");
        $(selector).swipe({
            swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
                if (direction == "left") {
                    $(".nivo-lightbox-next").trigger("click");
                }
                if (direction == "right") {
                    $(".nivo-lightbox-prev").trigger("click");
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).on('click', ".lightbox", function(){
       addSwipeTo(".nivo-lightbox-overlay");
    });
 });
```